# Application.restart() return null

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, application-restart

I'm trying to restart spring boot application after executing an application.

So I've added a context in the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) { context = SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args); }

    public static void restart() {
        ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            context.close();
            context = SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args.getSourceArgs());
        });

        thread.setDaemon(false);
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

To call the restart method, Here is the Service:

```
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    @Transactional
    public void saveMaths() {
        int maths = 0;
        List<User> users;
        try {
            users = userRepository.findByMathsWhereNull();
            for (User user : users) {
                maths = calculateMaths(user);
                user.setMaths(maths);
                userRepository.updateUser(maths, user.getId());
            }
        } finally {
            restart();
        }
    }

    public void restart() {
        Application.restart();
    }
```

But unfortunatelly, if the principal method works, I've a null pointer exception in the finally restart().
I've instanciated maths and users list just to be sure and once again, this method works. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you add the whole stack trace for the error?

Comment: What exacly is null?

Comment: I think the null come from user and exactely when I create the loop "for (User user : users)" - The stacktrace doesn't give any information, only that the restart() method can't be executed because of the java.lang.NullPointerException: null but nothing else to help...